# .slideToggle() on one DIV instead of all others with same class

Tags: jquery, html, hide, slidetoggle

I'm trying to create a menu with DIVs for Appetizers, Soups, etc. I use paragraph tabs as my toggler. All of my togglers have identical classes of "toggle". All of the DIV areas have the same class, "selection." How do I make it so when I click on a toggler, it just reveals the DIV class right above it. Sorry, my coding is messy.

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.toggle').click(function(){
    $('.selection').slideToggle("slow");
  });<br>
});
```

CSS:

```
.selection,.toggle
{
    width: 700px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    marign-lift: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    background: white;
    border: solid 2px gray;
}
.toggle
{
    text-align: center;
}
.selection
{
    display: none;
    text-align: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="selection">
    Special Appetizer 8.95 <br>
    Small Appetizer Plate 7.50
</div>
<p class="toggle">Appetizers</p>

<div class="selection">
    Broccoli & Cream Soup $5.50 <br>
    Clam Chowder 7.50
</div>
<p class="toggle">Soups</p>

<div class="selection">
    Fried Rice 4.95 <br>
</div>
<p class="toggle">Rice</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can target an item relative to the one that was clicked on like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.toggle').click(function(){
        $(this).prev('.selection').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

This will get the clicked on `.toggle` item and get the previous `.selection` item and slideToggle just that one.

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/2zJ8z/

I would suggest improving it so you can click on the .selection item to make it go away as this makes toggling to explore with the mouse a little easier:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.toggle').click(function(){
        $(this).prev('.selection').slideToggle("slow");
    });

    $('.selection').click(function(){
        $(this).slideToggle("slow");
    });
});​
```

You can see this minor enhancement here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/JrhNz/

If you want any other open ones to close when you open a new one, you could use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.toggle').click(function(){
        var prev = $(this).prev('.selection');
        $(this).siblings('.selection').not(prev).slideUp("slow");
        prev.slideToggle("slow");
    });

    $('.selection').click(function(){
        $(this).siblings('.selection').slideUp("slow");
        $(this).slideToggle("slow");
    });
});​
```

Demo of this option here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/JrhNz/6/

Comment: Would you happen to know how to make an open one close when another one opens?

Comment: @KarenZhen - I added an option to the end of my answer that closes any other open ones.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/):

```
$('.toggle').click(function(){
    $(this).prev('.selection').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: Would you happen to know how to make an open one close when another one opens?