# Creating a CSS Accordion Menu

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, accordion, dropdown

I'd like to create a menu using CSS and HTML (and JavaScript if needed) which acts like a regular accordion mobile menu. I'd like for all list elements to be clickable, and on tabs which have children, I'd like to put an arrow next to it open the dropdown when clicked. This way I can have the main list element's text serve as a button to open that particular page.
[image: Example]

```
`<ul class="nav-menu">
<li class=""><a href="">About</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="">News</a></li>
<li class="has_children"><a href="">Events</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="">For Children</a></li>
    <li><a href="">For Students</a></li>
    <li><a href="">For Families</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class=""><a href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>`
```

I've been looking for a good script for this approach while trying to develop my own. I don't have a ton of control over the HTML because I'm using the menus generated in Wordpress, whose HTML comes out to be something like the above.

Thanks!

Comment: How about a second link with a function to show / hide the submenu?

Answer (score 2):

I would give a class to the collapsible list and toggle it with `jQuery` `slideToggle()` -> http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

You can set default `display: none;` to it so it is not visible. After that add a class to the Events to trigger the click event and make the animation for slide in/out. For the arrow you can use an img and position it with `flexbox`. After that you can toggle another class to the img in the same click event where you also toggle the childern. This class rotates the img so the arrow shows the right way.

For understanding flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Below the working snippet.

```js
$(".clickme").click(function() {
  // toggle children
  $(".collapsible").slideToggle("slow", function() {});

  // rotate arrow
  $('.arrow').toggleClass('rotate');
});
```

```css
.list>li,
.collapsible>li {
  list-style: none;
}

.list li {
  border: 1px solid brown;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: lightyellow;
}

.collapsible {
  display: none;
}

.clickme {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.clickme .arrow {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.rotate {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list">
  <li><a href="">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="">News</a></li>
  <li class="clickme"><a href="">Events</a><img class="arrow" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-up-01-512.png" alt=""></li>
  <ul class="collapsible">
    <li><a href="">For Children</a></li>
    <li><a href="">For Students</a></li>
    <li><a href="">For Families</a></li>
  </ul>
  <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Almost there! I retooled this to work in the Wordpress framework, but there's one thing which is still a little messed up in this example. When I make more than one dropdown, and I click one to expand, they all expand. How do I make it so it's just the one?

Comment: ok, I was able to make it so it's just the one, but I'm far from finished. Since the Wordpress output is much different, I'm working to create a lot of inner logic and additional CSS to make it work. Is there anything that's already scripted out?

Comment: @Brendan check out this for your first question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642667/slidetoggle-on-one-div-instead-of-all-others-with-same-class

Comment: Ok, I've worked out some of the issues and I have a working menu. I made a jsfiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/120082/. My issue now is making the sub-submenus not respond when its submenu is clicked.

Comment: @Brendan I'll check it out. As I can see you are working with the idea of my answer, so my answer was the way that helped you. You should mark it as correct ;)